# Hello world program compilation exits with stream did not contain valid UTF-8

Tags: windows, rust

error: couldn't read main.rs: stream did not contain valid UTF-8

```
fn main(){
    println!("Hello,World!");
}
```

copy paste from the docs, for some reason doesn't run.
tried an empty main function as below but that didn't work either

```
fn main(){
}
```

what does the error mean when there's no string involved?

Comment: have you manually create that program or with command `cargo new program_name`

Comment: Probably means you're saving it in UTF-16 (which some Windows programs misleadingly call just "Unicode") instead of UTF-8. What program did you use to create the file?

Comment: used command touch "" > main.rs , does it matter?

Comment: It matters what encoding you saved the file in, so to the extent different programs have different defaults, yeah, it matters. The reason I asked is because depending on the program there may be a way to change the encoding (for example, in Notepad you can choose the encoding from a drop down menu in the Save As dialog box).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps,

```
$ cargo new hello
$ cd hello
$ cargo check
$ cargo run
```

and must install **visual studio build tools**.